# Change color of object by just pointing the mouse

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I wanna change the color of the circle from green to red by just pointing the arrow (mouse pointer) at the circle (no clicks). But for red circle the person must click on the circle to change the color. The circles should also change its position every time on the screen when clicked upon or hovered upon.

Basically, red dot - click, green dot - don't click. Both colors should alternate randomly, but red circle should pop up more, 65/35 ratio.

The code is in HTML, CSS and JavaScript (JS)

The demo currently looks like this: https://jsfiddle.net/sidsingh29/591hfwLd/20/

Second Solution: if this is not possible or too complicated, I'd like to just make all dots disappear after 1s without having any trigger. In this Red and Green cirlce both would disappear in 1 sec automatically, but red circle should pop up more often, 65/35 Red to Green ratio. Also when the colors change the position of the circle should also change on the screen to any random point on the screen. We need to make sure the circle does not go beyond the screen width/size.

** code **

```
HTML:


<div id="test"></div>


CSS:

#test {
    position:absolute;
    height: 70px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;}


JavaScript + jQuery (edge):


$('#test').click(function() {
  var docHeight = $(document).height(),
    docWidth = $(document).width(),
    $div = $('#test'),
    divWidth = $div.width(),
    divHeight = $div.height(),
    heightMax = docHeight - divHeight,
    widthMax = docWidth - divWidth;

  $div.css({
    left: Math.floor( Math.random() * widthMax ),
    top: Math.floor( Math.random() * heightMax ),
    background: Math.random() > 0.3 ? 'red' : 'green', 
  });
});
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/:hover

Answer (score 1):

To make it in basic CSS.

```css
#test {
  position:absolute;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

#test:hover {
  background-color : red;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

If you want to execute JSwhen the element is hovered use `.hover()` instead of `click()` in your code. You can also detect if the dot is currently red or green with `if (div.style.backgroundColor == "red")`

This code porpobaly don't work as you expect, because i don't undertand waht you want to do exactly, but it should give you and idear.

```js
$('#test').click(function() {
  if (document.getElementById("test").style.backgroundColor != "green") {
    var docHeight = $(document).height(),
    docWidth = $(document).width(),
    $div = $('#test'),
    divWidth = $div.width(),
    divHeight = $div.height(),
    heightMax = docHeight - divHeight,
    widthMax = docWidth - divWidth;

    $div.css({
      left: Math.floor( Math.random() * widthMax ),
      top: Math.floor( Math.random() * heightMax ),
      background: Math.random() > 0.3 ? 'red' : 'green', 
  });
 }
});

$('#test').hover(function() {
  if (document.getElementById("test").style.backgroundColor == "green" && $('#test').is(":hover")) {
    var docHeight = $(document).height(),
    docWidth = $(document).width(),
    $div = $('#test'),
    divWidth = $div.width(),
    divHeight = $div.height(),
    heightMax = docHeight - divHeight,
    widthMax = docWidth - divWidth;

    $div.css({
      left: Math.floor( Math.random() * widthMax ),
      top: Math.floor( Math.random() * heightMax ),
      background: Math.random() > 0.3 ? 'red' : 'green', 
  });
 }
});
```

```css
#test {
    position:absolute;
    height: 70px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: how can i control the hover? The green color changes when I just move the mouse. I want to hover the cursor on the green circle and then it should change color. Right now the green switches to red as soon as I touch the mouse. Green should switch when mouse arrow is hovered on top of it.

Comment: Add some delay so the dot is not condered has hovered instantly. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp*

Comment: can you please help me adding a delay of 1 sec? I cannot figure out where and how to add the delay.

Comment: @Sid I modify the snippet for that. But the question was about hoveing so if you considere that it's answered, tou can select this answer as solution and ask in an other post if you have other issues.

Comment: Hey Julien, I'm new to stackoverflow. Still getting the hang of it, My bad!! Will keep it in mind. Thank you for the help.